# Few conditions filter Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to a check a few conditions, so I filtered my RDD this way:

```
scala> file.filter(r => r(38)=="0").filter(r => r(2)=="0").filter(r => r(3)=="0").count
```

Is it correct as an alternative of "&&"?

Comment: Yes, It will wok like &&, of course. Not sure which will end up more efficient

Comment: I think that was the question -- is that the question: which is more efficient?

Comment: @david-griffin yes, it was like double question if I can use such expression and if it is the same efficient as using "&&" )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a series of filters is semantically equivalent to one filter with `&&` in your case.

`file.filter(r => r(38) == "0" && r(2) == "0" && r(3) == "0")`

However, the variant above is guaranteed to be faster than the earlier version. This can be established via the following:

1. `&&` is a short circuit operator, and the next comparison happens only if the first one evaluates to `true`. The number of comparisons in both the cases will be the **same** (yes!).
2. The multiple filter version involves three passes over the RDD vs. one pass for a single filter with `&&`.